# How to select strings in UUID format + case sensitive wildcards

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I select only strings in the format XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX where X is any number or any UPPERcase (not lowercase) character?

Example dataset:

```
ed54cb09-b402-4551-912d-b8e0fec69d9e --I do not want to select this one
00029B19-80CC-4FF8-BE11-BDB55FC7FC2A --I do want to select this one
```

Some are all-caps, some are not, and this is a varchar field. I want to select only these all-caps UUIDs, excluding the rest.

Currently I'm using the _ wildcard to look for the basic UUID format, but looks like UPPER doesn't apply to the _ wildcard. Ex.:

```
SELECT mycolumn
FROM mytable t
WHERE  t.mycolumn like UPPER('________-____-____-____-____________') COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_Cp1_CS_AS
```

Comment: You could attempt to convert it to a `uniqueidentifier` and filter to rows where the value is `NULL` from the attempted conversion.

Comment: If `MyColumn = Upper( MyColumn )` then you shouldn't have any issues with lowercase characters. [`Try_Convert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can handle the rest of the validation. Your usage of `Upper` with `like` doesn't make sense. Changing all of the lowercase underscores to uppercase won't accomplish much.

Comment: I missed that odd requirement, @DaleK . Seems like a `COLLATE` is needed too. Perhaps the requirements are part of an XY Problem. Why, for example, isn't the OP using a `uniqueidentifier` in the first place

Comment: Aside: From [RFC4122](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4122#section-3): "Each field is treated as an integer and has its value printed as a zero-filled hexadecimal digit string with the most significant digit first.  The hexadecimal values "a" through "f" are output as lower case characters and are case insensitive on input."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned, you can first check its all uppercase by comparing `upper` of your value with itself using a case sensitive collation. And then use your wildcard pattern (or a more precise one as shown below) to confirm the format is correct.

```
select
    -- Precise check on allowed characters
    case when upper(X.Test) = X.Test collate Latin1_General_CS_AI
        and X.Test like '[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]-[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]-[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]-[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]-[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9]' then 1 else 0 end
    -- Loose check on allowed character, but definitely upper case
    , case when upper(X.Test) = X.Test collate Latin1_General_CS_AI
        and X.Test like '________-____-____-____-____________' then 1 else 0 end     
    -- Not sure why HABO deleted their answer, but the following works also
    , case when upper(X.Test) = X.Test collate Latin1_General_CS_AI
        and try_convert(uniqueidentifier,X.Test) is not null then 1 else 0 end
    -- And combining Shmiel's and Charleface's suggestions gives
    , case when X.Test like replicate('[A-F0-9]', 8) + '-' + replicate('[A-F0-9]', 4) + '-' + replicate('[A-F0-9]', 4) + '-' + replicate('[A-F0-9]', 4) + '-' + replicate('[A-F0-9]', 12) collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2 then 1 else 0 end

from (
    values ('ed54cb09-b402-4551-912d-b8e0fec69d9e'), ('00029B19-80CC-4FF8-BE11-BDB55FC7FC2A')
) X (Test);
```

I have to echo Larnu's comment here, that it seems quite an odd requirement which might be better solved by a system change elsewhere.

Comment: You can use `REPLICATE(num_of_times,'[A-Z0-9]')` instead of typing it.

Comment: `Latin1_General_100_BIN2` would be more efficient, and UUIDs are in hex, which only uses `[A-F0-9]`, then there is no need for three different checks, that is an exact match for the format.

Comment: @Charlieface interestingly using `Latin1_General_CS_AI` with `LIKE` doesn't work but using `Latin1_General_100_BIN2` does. Can you explain why it performs better?

Comment: A binary collation will *always* perform better than any other collation: it isn't doing any collation, it's purely a byte comparison, so it's a very fast `REPZ CMPSB` on an x86 processor. Why `Latin1_General_CS_AI` doesn't work I don't know, it seems to work for me? Not convinced about `REPLICATE` that's probably gonna be slow calculating it on every row (although it's deterministic so maybe the compiler is clever enough to hoist it out) and it's not really any shorter

Comment: @Charlieface oh of course :) been a while since I considered the binary aspect. Um, see this [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8a442c21d6f727fffa374127e14c6c15) the first compare is not case sensitive.

Comment: After playing around with it, I've realized that `LIKE` doesn't seem to support multiple wildcard ranges. So I'm not entirely sure why a binary collation *does* work. You should have had `[0-9ABCDEF]`. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6808c58487d91b955e2a52ef9f8393f5

Comment: Weird, it seems to work with multiple ranges for a completely different character, but not with the collation.

Comment: @David curious to know which option you used in the end.